# js-cookie: How to use cookies in an if statement

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am using the [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) plugin and I want to know how to use it in an if statement. In my scenario I want to show a popup if the Cookie does not exist.

**Cookie**

```
Cookies.set('adModalOpen', 'true', { expires: 8/24 });
```

**If Statement**

```
if ( !Cookies.get('adModalOpen') === 'true' ) {
  // show popup
}
```

I've tried a using `=== Null` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just

```
if(!Cookies.get('adModalOpen')) {
 //show pop 
}
```

Comment: Magic! Thanks a mill

Comment: The original is this: `!(Cookies.get('adModalOpen')) === 'true'` -> `!('true') === 'true'` -> `false === 'true'` -> `false`. The suggested solution goes like this: `!(Cookies.get('adModalOpen'))` -> `!('true')` -> `false` and when returning `undefined`: `!(Cookies.get('adModalOpen'))` -> `!(undefined)` -> `true`. The correct solution using the original code would be like this: `!(Cookies.get('adModalOpen') === 'true')` -> `!('true' === 'true')` -> `!(true)` -> `false` the oppposite ``!(Cookies.get('adModalOpen') === 'true')`` -> `!(undefined === 'true')` -> `!(false)` -> `true` (too complex).